# how to get an checkbox by value generated with javascript

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I try to get an checkbox by value generated with javascript 
but my checkbox stay checked

```
$("input[value=varJs]").prop('checked', false);
```

I am not sure how to do this, is it possible?

Comment: Sure, i have created a quick example : https://jsfiddle.net/63djyp9e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to concatenate the variable into the selector, like this:

```
$("input[value=" + varJs + "]").prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: ,i tried but it doesn't work i updated my example : https://jsfiddle.net/63djyp9e/1/

Answer (score 0):

I got the "Solution"

But i'm not sure that optimize is good

```
var test = 'four';
var test1 = 'input[value='+test+']';
$(test1).prop('checked', true);
```